# print soup.prettify producing blank output

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda

I have tried the following codes to extract the page url.

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import urllib3

 http = urllib3.PoolManager()

 url = 'http://www.thefamouspeople.com/singers.php'
 response = http.request('GET', url)
 html = response.read()
 soup = BeautifulSoup(html)


 print soup.prettify()
```

But, I was wondering its giving blank output. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding `html = str(html)` after `html = response.read()` because `html = response.read()` returns bytes.

Comment: @ Michael Bluman Thanks. I modified it according to your suggestion but didn't get any output.

Comment: did you try printing html after the cast to str to see if it was empty?

Comment: @Harry if printing html was empty before and after the cast, then the problem isn't with beautifulsoup, it's with urllib3. You could try using urllib for the request.

Comment: Thanks. But documentation says urllib3 is better. Moreover urllib is not available. I tried to install it , but found errors.